# Cytoscape elements update messes up graph

Tags: plotly-dash, cytoscape, dash-cytoscape

With Plotly dash I have a callback that builds a cytoscape graph in preset mode.
The initial build is perfectly fine.

As the user updates a control, the same callback is triggered again and a new elements list is being generated.
The list has the same nodes as the original list but some of the edges and the styling of the nodes is different.

The result is a messed up graph that doesn't follow the styling I requested.
I triple checked the elements data and it is ok, so it seems that the issue is with Cytoscape not refreshing well.

The Cytoscape parameters I'm using are:

```
`userPanningEnabled=False,
responsive=True,
autolock=True,
autounselectify=True,
autoRefreshLayout=True,`
```